# Unmanaged switch in home network?

Tags: networking, router, lan, nas, switch

I have some knowledge but here I'm stuck and don't know how is going to work or if is possible !!??
I'm using an Asus NAS with 2.5Gb port and thinking of having high speed connection between NAS and PC! So I bought recently QHora WiFi router from QNAP, because its only as far as I see from my research which supports 2 LAN ports with 2.5GB or more!! But turn out the QNAP router its total rubbish and apart from those 2 10Gb LAN ports doesn't have too many thing to impress me !! so I decided to go back to Synology routers. So my question is : Is there any way of connect my PC and NAS to 2.5Gb unmanaged switch and rest of wireless devices in my LAN still to be able to see NAS and PC ??!
(Below I will attach a basic scheme how my LAN is working)

[image: my LAN scheme]

Answer (score 1):

Just connect the switch to the router.
Connect the NAS and PC to the swtich.

Comment: Note, you will onlt get the speed of the slowest connected device. So no, what you want isn't possible with that setup AFAIK.

Comment: That's not true. Speed of the slowest device is not a factor unless we're talking about communicating with that particular device.

Comment: Assuming we're talking a switch and not a hub, the switch should transfer data any two of its ports at the speed of the slower port. This is independent of the speed of any other port. As an example, if you have four ports A B C D, then AC can talk independently of BD, and potentially at different speeds. The backplane speed defines the maximum bandwidth of the switch (and is usually not declared for SOHO switches), so if the backplane speed is 1.5 Gb/s then AC could talk at 1 Gb/s _or_ BD could talk at 1 Gb/s, but combined they would be restricted to a total of 1.5 Gb/s

Comment: but that's exactly what i described to do , just don't know if this config will allow me full communication between all devices !!??

Comment: @G.I.Joe what do you mean by "full communication"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that actually you don't want a WiFi Router, you want a WiFi Access Point with a built-in two port switch. (Or a router reconfigured to be just an AP. That's often a cheaper solution and can work just as well if you get it right<sup>*</sup>.)

```
[ Modem/Router ] -- [ Access Point (WiFi) + Switch ]
                                |         |
                                |         |
                              [ PC ]   [ NAS ]
```

If you can't get an AP with a Switch you can run them as separate devices

```
[ Modem/Router ] -- [ = = = = = Switch = = = = = ]
                         |         |        |
                         |         |        |
                       [ PC ]   [ NAS ]   [ AP ]
```

In these configurations your ISP's modem/router is responsible for issuing LAN addresses through DHCP, regardless of whether a device is connected wired or wireless. Everything should be able to contact everything else, but the two wired devices should be able to communicate at wire speed whereas everything else will be dependent on their individual wireless connection speed.

---

<sup>* Switch off DHCP service, and don't use the WAN port at all.</sup>

Comment: Very interesting solutions !! but as i understand in these situations I'm loosing all traffic control and other things from synology router , unless I'll use managed switch ?!! what a problem when companies are st**d enough to not add 2 extra LAN ports in routers !! I think its about the time to have half of the LAN ports with more than 1Gb

Comment: @G.I.Joe that's because routers are not switches. It's only in end-cosumer devices where seperate function (switch, router, AP, etc.) are merged into one device and end-consumer devices mostly cover basic functions. But if you look around you might find and end-consumer router with your specs anyway.